# I have a hard time reading handwritten characters, and was hoping for some help figuring out this script

Tags: translation, character-identification, handwriting

I cannot read handwritten Chinese and was hoping some kind people could help me figure out the characters on the bottom of a bronze. Thank you in advance.

[image: writing on bronze]

Comment: omg, it's so hard to reading it, I'm almost can't make it. although I'm a native Chinese speaker.

Answer (score 2):

I think the characters are:

至人皆咏梅稍月, 高士行吟竹外风?